# Leer una lista de dicionario

Tags: python, json

tengo el siguiente fichero Json.

```
{
  "AFB": [
    {
      "politica": [
        {
          "Sistemas": [
            {
              "icon": "icon_sys"
            },
            {
              "scripts": [
                "os_preg4",
                "os_preg14"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "Sudo": [
            {
              "icon": "icon_sys"
            },
            {
              "scripts": [
                "sudo_preg4",
                "sudo_preg14"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "INFRA": [
    {
      "politica": [
        {
          "Sistemas": [
            {
              "icon": "icon_sys"
            },
            {
              "scripts": [
                "os_preg4",
                "os_preg14"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Y lo intento leer y recorrer pero no consigo lo deseado, lo que quiero es guardar en una variable el valor del icon, y en otra el valor de los scripts.

por ahora tengo esto que si me funciona, me imprime el cliente que paso como clave y las politicas, con sus respectivos diccionarios, y ya mas no consigo

```
import json
with open('/home/lopuma/Compliance/.conf/clientes.json') as op:
    data = json.load(op)
    for clt in data['AFB']:
        print("cliente {}, politicas {}".format('AFB',clt['politica']))
        for pol in clt['politica']:
            print("politica, en linea : ", pol)
            for sis_pol in pol:
                print("Sis : ", sis_pol)
                for politica in pol[sis_pol]:
                    lista = list(politica.keys())
                    print("lista : ", lista)
```

Añado la salida del comando, pero no se como conseguir en una variable solo el valor del icon y en otra solo el valor del cada item de la lista de scrips.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Parsear* ficheros json no es nada fácil.

Intentaría primero pasar de la estructura JSON a una más manejable en python empleando una *compresión* de listas y diccionarios:

```py
import json

with open('/home/lopuma/Compliance/.conf/clientes.json') as op:
    data = json.load(op)

politicas = {
    tipo : { k : { "icon": v[0]["icon"], "scripts": v[1]["scripts"] }
           for pol in pols[0]["politica"]
           for k,v in pol.items() }
    for tipo, pols in data.items()
}
```

```
>>> politicas
{'AFB': {
    'Sistemas': {
        'icon': 'icon_sys',
        'scripts': ['os_preg4', 'os_preg14']},
    'Sudo': {
        'icon': 'icon_sys',
        'scripts': ['sudo_preg4', 'sudo_preg14']}},
 'INFRA': {
    'Sistemas': {
        'icon': 'icon_sys',
        'scripts': ['os_preg4', 'os_preg14']}}}
```

Y luego ya puedes sacar listas por separado o como necesites:

```py
icons = [ x["icon"] for pol in politicas.values() for x in pol.values() ]
scripts = [ x["scripts"] for pol in politicas.values() for x in pol.values() ]
```

Trabajar con diccionarios anidados es bastante engorroso. Podemos usar *dataclasses* para facilitar el manejo:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Politica:
    tipo: str
    icon: str
    scripts: list[str]

politicas = {
    tipo : [ Politica( k, v[0]["icon"], v[1]["scripts"] )
           for pol in pols[0]["politica"]
           for k,v in pol.items() ]
    for tipo, pols in data.items() }
```

```
>>> politicas
{'AFB': [
    Politica(nombre='Sistemas', icon='icon_sys', scripts=['os_preg4', 'os_preg14']),
    Politica(nombre='Sudo', icon='icon_sys', scripts=['sudo_preg4', 'sudo_preg14'])],
'INFRA': [
    Politica(nombre='Sistemas', icon='icon_sys', scripts=['os_preg4', 'os_preg14'])]}
```

Comment: Lo mismo que comente al compañero de arriba, la respuesta funciona, pero no logro asociarlo a lo que quiero.

Comment: Faltaba contexto para saber qué es lo que buscas. Por lo que veo, a cada cliente le asocias varias políticas, donde cada política tiene un icono y una serie de scripts. Si es así, tienes unas *entidades* (cliente, política,...) con una serie de *atributos*, algo que se puede modelizar con clases en lugar de diccionarios. Pero eso es una cuestión distinta a leer simplemente un fichero json.

Comment: Correcto es asi como lo indicas, tienes algun video o algo donde pueda orientarme con lo que dices,.

Comment: No tengo ninguna relación de vídeos, pero estos temas son comunes a muchos cursos de base de datos. Encontrarás bastante información si busca por ["Modelo Entidad-Relación" (ERD)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modelo_entidad-relaci%C3%B3n). En el libro ["Python GUI Programming with Tkinter"](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-gui-programming/9781801815925/) parece que hay alguna cosa relacionado con tkinter y ERD.

Answer (score 2):

El primer paso para tratar con json es convertir la cadena que contiene ese json a una estructura python (diccionario, lista). Este primer paso es trivial pues te lo hace `json.loads()` que viene con la biblioteca estándar python y que ya sabes utilizar.

Pero una vez tenemos la estructura de datos python, "bucear" dentro de ella puede ser complicado, especialmente si queremos hacer búsquedas complicadas en diccionarios muy anidados. Para ayudar con este problema hay varias librerías. Mostraré aquí una de ellas, llamada [jsonpath_ng](https://github.com/h2non/jsonpath-ng) que implementa el estándar [JSONPath](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) que es un minilenguaje de consulta que permite escribir expresiones sencillas para encontrar cosas dentro de diccionarios y listas. Una especie de "expresiones regulares" para datos en vez de para texto.

Por ejemplo, una expresión como la siguiente:

```
AFB..icon
```

Significa "dentro de la clave AFB quiero obtener todas las apariciones de la clave 'icon', sin que importe el nivel de anidación en que aparezcan" (eso representan los dos puntos `..`).

En [esta web](https://jsonpath.com/) puedes probar a meter tu JSON en el panel de la izquierda y una expresión JSONPath (como la que te acabo de indicar) en el input de texto superior, y ver qué sale.

### Uso de jsonpath_ng

Lo primero necesitas tenerla instalada, pues no viene con Python. El uso típico de esta biblioteca consiste en importar su parser de expresiones JSONPath así:

```
from jsonpath_ng.ext import parse
```

y usarlo para crear "buscadores" como este:

```
ejemplo = parse("AFB..icon")
```

el cual después se puede aplicar sobre los datos que tengas (los cuales serán ya el resultado de haber leido el fichero o cadena con `json.loads()`), por ejemplo así:

```
resultado = ejemplo.find(data)
```

Ese resultado es iterable, y cada elemento resultante tiene un campo llamado `.value` que contiene lo que a ti te interesa.

## Solución

Podemos usar por tanto todo esto para crear una función que reciba como parámetro un usuario (ej: "AFB") y retorne una tupla con dos listas, por un lado la lista de "icon" y por otro la lista e "scripts". La función sería así:

```
def icons_and_scripts(user, data):
  busca_icons = parse(f"{user}..icon")
  busca_scripts = parse(f"{user}..scripts")
  icons = [e.value for e in busca_icons.find(data)]
  scripts = [e.value for e in busca_scripts.find(data)]
  return icons, scripts
```

Ahora supongamos que leemos tus datos:

```
import json
with open('/home/lopuma/Compliance/.conf/clientes.json') as op:
    data = json.load(op)
```

Entonces ya podríamos usar la función así:

```
icons, scripts = icons_and_scripts("AFB", data)
```

Y el resultado sería la lista `['icon_sys', 'icon_sys']` en `icons` y la lista `[['os_preg4', 'os_preg14'], ['sudo_preg4', 'sudo_preg14']]`  en `scripts`.

### Más posibilidades

Incluso puedes pasar como nombre de usuario `"*"` que actúa como comodín y por tanto encaja con cualquier usuario. Así obtendrías todos los "icon" (o "scripts") sin que importe de qué usuario es cada uno, en el orden en que aparecen:

```
print(icons_and_scripts("*", data))
---
(['icon_sys', 'icon_sys', 'icon_sys'],
 [['os_preg4', 'os_preg14'],
  ['sudo_preg4', 'sudo_preg14'],
  ['os_preg4', 'os_preg14']])
```

O si quieres puedes iterar por las claves del diccionario `data` y llamar a nuestra función para cada usuario, por ejemplo con algo como esto:

```
for user in data:
  icons, scripts = icons_and_scripts(user, data)
  print(f"User: {user}")
  print(f"  icons: {icons}")
  print(f"  scripts: {scripts}")
```

lo que produciría:

```
User: AFB
  icons: ['icon_sys', 'icon_sys']
  scripts: [['os_preg4', 'os_preg14'], ['sudo_preg4', 'sudo_preg14']]
User: INFRA
  icons: ['icon_sys']
  scripts: [['os_preg4', 'os_preg14']]
```

Comment: El comando funciona, pero no me ha sido util para lo que quiero, tengo una APP en TKINTER, tengo un frame, que con un for me leer el JSON y me crea un boton por USER : AFB, ese boton se asocia a una funcion, que depende que user sea, me crea un frame con las politicas que tenga ese fichero JSON, por ejemplo USER:INFRA, politica, ssh, USER : AFB, politicas : sistemas y sudo,te dejo una imagen en la pregunta.

Comment: LO que quiero añadir es, automáticamente se añada un icono a cada política, ya sea system, su icono que esta asociado a la clave icon, a su ves esta asociada al valor de la clave politica.. osea que si es una politica sudo, que me añada al boton el icono para sudo, pero es eso lo que no consigo hacer.

Comment: No entiendo lo que dices, pero parece una pregunta diferente. Habías preguntado cómo extraer en listas separadas los iconos y los scripts, y eso es lo que te hemos respondido. Lo que quieras hacer después con los iconos es otra cosa, y si los iconos dependen de los scripts de una forma que no me ha quedado clara parece que eso es ya una nueva pregunta.

Comment: Si tienes razon, aun asi muchas gracias